# ODP.Net Connection Pooling Behavior

Tags: c#, oracle, connection, connection-pooling

I am using ODP.Net Managed Driver to develop an online solution.

As I recall, Oracle connection pooling is based on "Connection String", different connection string will create different connection pool.
Ref:  https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/win.102/b14307/featConnecting.htm#i1006393

```
The connection pooling service creates connection pools by using the 
ConnectionString property as a signature, to uniquely identify a pool.
```

However, in SQL Server Ref: [2]: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca(v=vs.110).aspx

```
Connections are pooled per process, per application domain, per connection 
string and when integrated security is used, per Windows identity. Connection 
strings must also be an exact match; keywords supplied in a different order 
for the same connection will be pooled separately.
```

Now my colleague is arguing with me about Oracle pooling is distinguished by AP and connection string. But I think it's only connection string.

For example:
    Application [A]:  Connection String [A]
    Application [B]:  Connection String [A]
    Above will use the same connection pool.

But my colleague says
    Application [A]:  Connection String [A]
    Application [B]:  Connection String [A] 
    Will use different connection pool.

Am I right about this?  Please give me an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The will use a different pool in my experience.  I run a distribute application and each instance of the same application with the same connection string and same user gets a pool.